# Detect if map implementation supports incomplete types

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I want to see if a map implementation supports incomplete types, as libc++ seems to support them, but not stdlibc++.

I tried SFINAE here, but it gives a compilation error:

```
template<template<typename, typename, typename...> typename MapType, typename = void>
struct allows_incomplete : std::false_type {};

struct incomplete_type;
template<template<typename, typename, typename...> typename MapType>
struct allows_incomplete<MapType, std::void_t<decltype(MapType<std::string_view, incomplete_type>{})>> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(allows_incomplete<std::map>::value);
static_assert(!allows_incomplete<std::unordered_map>::value);
```

Comment: Don't see any errors except from static asserts on some compilers. Can you be more specifc?

Comment: @sklott Sure, take https://godbolt.org/z/d7hnMbn4c Both the last assertion and the negation of the last assertion fail.

Comment: Yes, it looks like bug in GCC, althrough I didn't seen it when I checked some other gcc version (don't rememeber which it was...). BUT you check here for possibility to *construct* map with incomplete type, which probably is not what you need. But checking for possibility to *declare* map with incomplete type there seems to be no issues.

Comment: @sklott What I'm actually interested in is if I can define a type X such that X contains a member of type std::unordered_map<std::string_view, X>. If I try to test this more directly (with a helper structure with such a member) I get into the same compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to see if a map implementation supports incomplete types, as libc++ seems to support them, but not stdlibc++.

This is basically impossible.

First, because member functions of class templates are lazily instantiated, "support" for incomplete types is not a binary yes or no. Perhaps one can instantiate the class, but not use it. Perhaps one can default construct the class, but not copy it. At least some member functions will typically have completeness as a precondition.

The question tests default constructibility. However, the comments suggest the actual desire is to define a type with the map as a member, which only requires instantiation. To test this, for example, replace `M{}` with `typename M::value_type` where `M` is the map type.

Second, to test this with SFINAE, one stills need the class template author's support. SFINAE only tests failures in the immediate context. Any other errors are still hard errors. These are the type of errors from libstdc++. This also explains the `is_constructible` observation in @sklott's answer. It is not a bug.

Third, testing completeness for reasons other than to fail compilation is dangerous. Static data members of class templates can be instantiated at the end of the translation unit (but before the private module fragment). They must give the same answer wherever they are instantiated. If one had a hypothetical `is_complete_v<T>`, any translation unit that instantiates it with `T` incomplete must not complete `T`. Any translation unit that completes `T` must not include the declaration that depends on `is_complete_v<T>`. While possible, this would be very fragile.

Fourth, standard C++ says it is undefined to instantiate `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` with an incomplete type. Compilation failure is actually the nice option here versus walking into a trap.

The consequence of the second, third, and fourth points is that you can only do this on implementations that agree to let you as an extension to standard C++.

libc++ supports instantiation as an extension. See [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/test/std/containers/associative/map/incomplete_type.pass.cpp) and [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/test/std/containers/unord/unord.map/incomplete_type.pass.cpp). I cannot find documentation of the extension but it is in the test suite.

So the only real solution is this:

```
#include <version>
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if map supports incomplete type you need to determine if such map is complete type itself or not.
The only difference between complete and incomplete type is that it is not possible to get size of incomplete type, i.e. its impossible to get `sizeof()` of incomplete type. So, we can construct detector for incomplete types based on this. Something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {
    template<int N>
    struct test {using type = void;};
}

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_complete<T, typename detail::test<sizeof(T)>::type> : std::true_type {};

struct incomplete_type;
struct complete_type {};

template<template<typename, typename, typename...> typename MapType>
using allows_incomplete = is_complete<MapType<int, incomplete_type>>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_complete<incomplete_type>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_complete<complete_type>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_complete<std::map<int, incomplete_type>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_complete<std::unordered_map<int, incomplete_type>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << allows_incomplete<std::map>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << allows_incomplete<std::unordered_map>::value << std::endl;
}
```

---

BTW, GCC 11.3 seems to have bug, because even `std::is_constructible<std::unordered_map<int, incomplete_type>>::value` gives same error and this is defenitelly incorrect.

Comment: This does not seem to work though: https://godbolt.org/z/ob8bPcj34 - it prints "true" for allows_incomplete<std::unordered_map> for gcc and std::unordered_map<int, incomplete_type> instantiation does not compile.

Comment: @dewaffled This check is not for instantiation, but for declaration. I.e. its possible to have declaration of such type: `struct X { std::unordered_map<int, X> v; };`. And it will be possible to instantiate such type, since `X` will be complete at instantiation time.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, instantiation with incomplete type of course cannot compile. But this approach still does not seem to be working: `struct X { std::unordered_map<int, X> v; };` actually compiles with gcc 12+ and allows_incomplete = true. But for previous gcc versions struct declaration does not compile (impletementation does requires complete type) allows_incomplete also gives compilation error.

Comment: And with gcc 12+ you get the same compilation error with `template <typename T> struct S{ T x; };` and `std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_complete<S<incomplete_type>>::value << std::endl;` It is just unordered_map impletementation changed in a way it allows incomplete types.

Comment: @dewaffled I already edited my answer to add that version GCC 11.3 seems to be bugged, since even library `std::is_constructible` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Or may be I just don't understand how exactly it should work...

Comment: Yeah, and clang also gives the same error for `template <typename T> struct S{ T x; };`